# MVC4-Deployment "Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.Core, Version=4.0.0.0"?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to deploy a simple intranet application on my local machine. I've included the deployable assemblies and have deployed it in asp.netv4 app pool but when I try to browse the application i get the below error.

Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Could anyone please help ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should do  is to go to your MVC web application project and expand the `References` node in the project tree. Select the `DotNetOpenAuth` assemblies and in the `Properties` dialog, set `Copy Local` to `True.` and then deploy it.

Answer (score 0):

```
MVC.NETProject->References->Remove OAuth*
```